# TypeInitializationException with separate Class

Tags: oracle, class

i have a little program to monitor my oracle DB's.

So i have a Class DBConn: (extremely shortened)

```
class DBConn
{
    private OracleConnection conn_oraconn = new OracleConnection();
    OracleCommand cmd_oracmd;
    static string str_oraconn;
    OracleDataReader dr;
    Logger log = new Logger();
    private String str_cname;

    public DBConn(String str_connname) 
    {
        str_cname = str_connname;
    }
}
```

In the main Form i initialize this by: (extremely shortened)

```
 public partial class frm_main : Form
 {
    TNSEntries availtns = new TNSEntries();
    bool gettns = false;
    Logger applog = new Logger();
    //List<DBConn> dbconn = new List<DBConn>();
    DBConn mydb;
    String std_user, std_password, std_db;

    private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           mydb = new DBConn(cmb_dbs.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
  }
```

So i start the programm and if i click the button i get the error in the line 
`private OracleConnection conn_oraconn = new OracleConnection();` in CLass `DBConn`. I don't understand why.

If i put this member directly under `public partial class frm_main : Form` it works.

Answer (score 0):

i found the error. 
The "OracleDataAccess.ddl" was the reason. I switched the version and all is fine.

Thanks!